# How to control the "dots" in a file name in R?

Tags: r

I want to copy certain files in a directory and I am using this function thanks to stack-overflow.

```
    f <- list.files( path = "C:\\New folder (3)" , pattern = "*.envi" , full.names = TRUE )
    n <- 5
   lapply( seq_len( length(f) ) , function(x) { lapply( seq_len( n ) , function( x ,y ){
   file.copy( f[x] , paste0( sub("^([^.]*).*", "\\1", f[x] ) , "-" , y , ".envi" ) )
    } , x = x )
    } )
```

this worked fine but my problem is that my files have several dots in their names.

example
my file:

```
           sm.0001.sgridand138.envi
```

the code produces

```
              sm-1.envi
```

but I want to consider the second dot and be

```
           sm.0001-1.envi
```

any hints please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that you want to cut away the part of the string starting at the second dot counted from the back. Replace

```
sub("^([^.]*).*", "\\1", f[x] )
```

by

```
sub("^(.*)\\.[^.]*\\.[^.]*$", "\\1", f[x] )
```

For `f[x] <- "this.is.a.test` the new expression yields

```
> sub("^(.*)\\.[^.]*\\.[^.]*$", "\\1", "this.is.a.test")
[1] "this.is"
```

Comment: The purpose of this construct is to duplicate the files in the same directory with modified names. The R return value indicates whether the file.copy operation was successful. On my machine the code produced new files of the desired format. Maybe file.copy failed on yours because of lack of write permission to the destination directory?